# A mysterious tv show about a weird alien gel area that starts to grow on Earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

I remember a TV show I saw some years ago. It was about a weird area that starts to grow on Earth. Scientists can't control it, and we understand it's connected with aliens.

Humans send some people in it to find out something about it, but they lose connection with them immediately. I remember a woman that comes back from that (actually she didn't come back by herself but I can't remember how!), and sometimes she remembers some things about some experiments that unknown creatures did on her. I think they found a dead alien body too.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Any details you could give, like your best guess at when you watched it, language it was in and what country you watched it in would help a lot.

Comment: Were the humans being sent into the alien area civilians or members of the armed forces? Did they walk in or fly in? The "weird area that starts to grow on Earth" reminds me of the BBC TV series Invasion:Earth from 1998. That also had a woman returning after being abducted by the aliens. I recall the alien scheme was to harvest humanity for serotonin, but I only ever saw the final half of the last episode. Humanity had reached the "time to detonate the thermonuclear weapon on British soil phase", so quite downbeat for early evening television.

Comment: @HandsomeJim: I also immediately thought of Invasion: Earth (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion:_Earth_(TV_series) ). Maybe you should expand that into an actual answer.

Answer (score 5):

From what I remember of BBC TV series [Invasion: Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion:_Earth_(TV_series)) from 1998 and reading the wiki (thanks Klaus) I think that is the show.

- The show features "an amorphous mountain of alien tentacles and design" that aliens (called nDs) are causing to grow on Earth.
- A character, Dr Amanda Tucker, is sucked into an alien portal and then returned. Later in the series she uses her "growing self-awareness of the alien mindset" to guide a jet bomber into and out of the structure.
- The final member of another alien species (called Echos) opposed to the invaders brings news that their race has chosen to commit "self-genocide rather than allow the nDs to harvest their race for their malignant end" before it too is killed on Earth.

So the show has the weird alien area, the returning woman with knowledge of the aliens and the dead alien.